# FireMonkey XE5 - Livebinding - TGrid - Cell text aligment

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, tgrid

I have a Firemonkey Desktop Application for Windows. I have a `TGrid` which I populate through a visual livebinding `TBindSourceDB` component. I want some columns to have text aligned to the right, as they are numerical values. I have tried through:

- `onPainting` event
- getting the `TTextCell` control by number of `ColumnxRow`
- typecasting it and setting `TextAlignt` property to the right

None of those measures align the text to the right. I have tried to set it at runtime, unsuccessfully though, getting the `TStyledControl` and assigning procedures to the `onApplyStyleLookup` of the `TTextCell`.

Any ideas on it? The App runs, but nothing happens. The cell texts are still left aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [OnDrawColumnCell](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Grid.TGrid.OnDrawColumnCell) Event.

For columns containing text cells, the text layout information for each individual Column is assigned from the [TextSettings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Controls.TTextControl.TextSettings) property of the grid. However, the assignment is performed prior to the event firing.

The best and simplest way is to just directly access the layout for a specific column via a class helper before any drawing takes place.

Set the [DefaultDrawing](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Grid.TCustomGrid.DefaultDrawing) property of the grid to **False** and paste the following code:

```
interface
  type
    TColumnHelper = class helper for FMX.Grid.TColumn
        function getTextLayout: TTextLayout;
    end;

implementation

{ TColumnHelper }    
function TColumnHelper.getTextLayout: TTextLayout;
begin
  Result := Self.FDrawLayout;
end;

{ OnDrawColumnCell }
procedure GridDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Canvas: TCanvas;
  const Column: TColumn; const Bounds: TRectF; const Row: Integer;
  const Value: TValue; const State: TGridDrawStates);
begin

  { change text layout info prior to default drawing }
  if Column.Header = 'Numerical Column' then
    Column.getTextLayout.HorizontalAlign := TTextAlign.Trailing
  else
    Column.getTextLayout.HorizontalAlign := TGrid(Sender).TextSettings.HorzAlign;

  { perform default drawing }
  TGrid(Sender).DefaultDrawColumnCell(Canvas, Column, Bounds, Row, Value, State);
end;
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. I just had to add FMX.Textlayout to the Uses clause.
Thank you so much.