# C++ Builder XE6 Firemonkey - How to align a column to right in TStringGrid

Tags: c++, alignment, c++builder, firemonkey, tstringgrid

Could anyone tell me please how can I align one or two columns within a StringGrid as TStringColumn doesn't have text settings but TStringGrid has. When I align grom TStringGrid text settings unfortunately it align all columns..

Or does anyone can give me a sample example how to use TGrid object..

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410901/firemonkey-xe5-livebinding-tgrid-cell-text-aligment

Comment: The link you have provided is in Delphi. I don't have any idea how to convert Delphi codes in to C++ Codes. I tired once but unfortunately I couldn't do that.. I want to repeat my question

Comment: I need to know how can I align a column to RIGHT in TSTRINGGRID

Comment: If you don't have answer for that one , please give me a small sample how to use TGRID in C++ Builder please.